# How to dynamically initialise both the column name and column data for a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get data based on a list and then add the data corresponding to this list attributes to the column under the name of the list element Ex below:

```
import pandas as pd

lis = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

output_df = pd.DataFrame()
u = 0
for i in lis:
    get_data = download_data_from_csv(xxxxxxxxxxxx_i)
    # Assume get_data is a column array
    output_df.at[u, 'Name'] = i
    output_df['Name'] = get_data
    u = u+1
```

How to make data in a format where each attribute will have its own column and its data under it while reading through the attribute list

Expected output:

```
a   b   c
1   7   4
6   10  9
```

a was stored as (1,6) b was stored as (7,10) c was stored as (4,9)

Comment: 1. Please provide an example of the expected dataframe. 2. Don't use `list` as a variable name. 3. This is not a list anyway, this is a set.

Comment: Edited the question, please check if its clear now?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({i:download_data_from_csv(xxx_i) for i in lis})` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it was as simple as this:

```
import pandas as pd

lis = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

output_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in lis:
    get_data = download_data_from_csv(xxxxxxxxxxxx_i)
    # Assume get_data is a column array
    output_df[i] = get_data
```

Comment: Just realized that this is a self-answered question. Do `pd.DataFrame({i:download_data_from_csv(xxx_i) for i in lis})`.

Comment: Can but agree with comprehension here. Post you answer so we may upvote it. How does it differ from Corralien's answer though?

Comment: @OCa I was trying to figure out, posted the question and then before anyone had answered, I found the bug in my code and asnwered it, seems reasonable to me, anyone else who reads this post sometime later will have the answer. Not here for some points

Answer (score 0):

Collect your data as `Series` then use `pd.concat` to merge them and finally `unstack` the first level (name in `lis`) to get the expected output:

```
# Dummy function to simulate downloaded data
def download_data_from_csv(i):
    """Simulate data"""
    d = {'a': [1, 6], 'b': [7, 10], 'c': [4, 9]}
    return d[i]

lis = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # Use a list not a set!
get_data = {i: pd.Series(download_data_from_csv(i)) for i in lis}
output_df = pd.concat(get_data).unstack(level=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> output_df
   a   b  c
0  1   7  4
1  6  10  9
```